# how to submit code in codeforce codechef etc?

Tags: python

I tried a simple problem at codeforce
http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/389/A
this is my solution

```
def main():
    input_size = int(input())
    numbers = []
    for i in range(input_size):
        #print('Enter ',i,' value')
        numbers.append(int(input()))
    #print(numbers)
    zeros_count,i = 0,0
    while True:
        #print(numbers)
        i=i%(input_size-1)
        if numbers[i]<numbers[i+1]:
            numbers[i+1] = numbers[i+1]-numbers[i]
            #print(i+1,'-',i,end='\n\n')
            zeros_count = 0
        elif numbers[i]>numbers[i+1]:
            numbers[i]=numbers[i]-numbers[i+1]
            #print(i,'-',i+1,end='\n\n')
            zeros_count = 0
        if numbers[i] == numbers[i+1]:
            zeros_count+=1
            #print(i,'and',i+1,'are equal');
        i+=1
        if zeros_count == input_size-1:
            break
        if zeros_count == 20:
            break;
    s = 0;
    for i in range(0,input_size,1):
        s+=numbers[i];
    print(s);
main()
```

this code is working fine on my computer but when i submit it, they say runtime error in 1st case that is 2 1 2. Most probably something is wrong in the way i take input or give output.
 Would you please tell me where am i doing it wrong.. similar problem comes when i tried to submit a code in codechef

Comment: Why don't you try http://discuss.codechef.com/?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your logic is wrong . Your code is running infinitely in while loop.
Here is my correct code in python

```
n=int(input())
a=map(int,raw_input().split())
a.sort()
while(True):
if(a[0]==a[n-1]):
    break;
for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
    if(a[i]>a[i-1]):    
        a[i]=a[i]-a[i-1]
a.sort()
print sum(a)
```